# how to make disabled select box to clickable (in webkit browsers)

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser, pointer-events

i need to set my disabled input select box to clickable in webkit browsers (under IE is working, under chrome,opera,safari not).

My page structure is the next:

```
<a id="..." href="#"><select id="...">(its disabled by jquery)</select><span>(its a custom jquery select box)</span></a>
```

my page do the next steps:

/1. add new href to

```
<a id="...">
```

/2. set new color for custom jquery select box then set is to disabled

In IE i can click to disabled select box but in webkit browsers
(chrome,safari) and in firefox i cant :(

I try to add pointer-events:none to my disabled select box (all way: by jquery, by css) but the custom jquery select box (span) is inherit the pointer-evenets:none setting too. Its working only when i manualy disable (in chrome developer tools) the second pointer-events setting (from span).

Please help :{

Comment: You shouldn't be able to click a disabled element. That is the point of it being disabled. Do you wish to enable it again?

Comment: @JonP is right. Instead of disabling it, you should bind onchange event to set value back to previous one.

Comment: A `select` element within an `a` element is invalid HTML btw.